# model failed to converge and multiple warnings using glmer

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I am an R newbie and trying to use glmer to help with my dissertation. I was using Stat v16 but meglm won't allow me to use gamma distribution and link identity so I came to R to execute this. Unfortunately, I still can't get the full model to converge.

Not sure if this helps at all but this is what I was trying to do in Stata:

```
meglm countOutcome Exposure##c.TimePeriod1 Exposure##c.TimePeriod2 Exposure##c.TimePeriod3 Exposure##c.TimePeriod4 covariate1 covariate2  covariate3, || SBA:, family(gaussian) link(identity) covariance(unstructured) offset(area) reml
```

Here is what I have tried...

First attempt:

```
summary(glmer(countOutcome ~ 1 + Exposure.f*TimePeriod1 + Exposure.f*TimePeriod2 + Exposure.f*TimePeriod3 + Exposure.f*TimePeriod4 + covariate1 + covariate2 + covariate3 + (1 | SBA), data=data,family=Gamma(link=identity)))
```

```
fit warnings:
Some predictor variables are on very different scales: consider rescaling
convergence code: 0
unable to evaluate scaled gradient
Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 4 negative eigenvalues
failure to converge in 10000 evaluations

Warning messages:
1: Some predictor variables are on very different scales: consider rescaling 
2: In (function (fn, par, lower = rep.int(-Inf, n), upper = rep.int(Inf,  :
  failure to converge in 10000 evaluations
3: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  unable to evaluate scaled gradient
4: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 4 negative eigenvalues
5: In vcov.merMod(object, use.hessian = use.hessian) :
  variance-covariance matrix computed from finite-difference Hessian is
not positive definite or contains NA values: falling back to var-cov estimated from RX
6: In vcov.merMod(object, correlation = correlation, sigm = sig) :
  variance-covariance matrix computed from finite-difference Hessian is
not positive definite or contains NA values: falling back to var-cov estimated from RX
```

I rescaled the covariates by centering on the grand mean and still got warnings.

```
fit warnings:
Some predictor variables are on very different scales: consider rescaling
convergence code: 0
unable to evaluate scaled gradient
Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 4 negative eigenvalues
failure to converge in 10000 evaluations

Warning messages:
1: Some predictor variables are on very different scales: consider rescaling 
2: In (function (fn, par, lower = rep.int(-Inf, n), upper = rep.int(Inf,  :
  failure to converge in 10000 evaluations
3: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  unable to evaluate scaled gradient
4: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 4 negative eigenvalues
5: In vcov.merMod(object, use.hessian = use.hessian) :
  variance-covariance matrix computed from finite-difference Hessian is
not positive definite or contains NA values: falling back to var-cov estimated from RX
6: In vcov.merMod(object, correlation = correlation, sigm = sig) :
  variance-covariance matrix computed from finite-difference Hessian is
not positive definite or contains NA values: falling back to var-cov estimated from RX
```

Then, I rescaled the covariates by per 1000 person and still got warnings.

```
convergence code: 0
unable to evaluate scaled gradient
Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 3 negative eigenvalues

Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  unable to evaluate scaled gradient
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 3 negative eigenvalues
3: In vcov.merMod(object, use.hessian = use.hessian) :
  variance-covariance matrix computed from finite-difference Hessian is
not positive definite or contains NA values: falling back to var-cov estimated from RX
4: In vcov.merMod(object, correlation = correlation, sigm = sig) :
  variance-covariance matrix computed from finite-difference Hessian is
not positive definite or contains NA values: falling back to var-cov estimated from RX
```

After looking through several very helpful posts on Stack Exchange I tried three more approached but not no avail... Suggestions are most welcome.

Attempt with bobyqa as optimizer:

```
summary(glmer(countOutcome ~ 1 + Exposure.f*TimePeriod1 + Exposure.f*TimePeriod2 + Exposure.f*TimePeriod3 + Exposure.f*TimePeriod4 + covariate1 + covariate2 + covariate3 + (1 | SBA),
              data=data, REML= TRUE, 
              family=Gamma(link=identity)), control=glmerControl(
                optimizer="bobyqa",optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)))


convergence code: 0
unable to evaluate scaled gradient
Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 3 negative eigenvalues

Warning messages:
1: extra argument(s) ‘REML’ disregarded 
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  unable to evaluate scaled gradient
3: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 3 negative eigenvalues
4: In summary.merMod(glmer(sba_nyc_fe_c ~ 1 + Gcode.f * T + Gcode.f *  :
  additional arguments ignored
5: In vcov.merMod(object, use.hessian = use.hessian) :
  variance-covariance matrix computed from finite-difference Hessian is
not positive definite or contains NA values: falling back to var-cov estimated from RX
6: In vcov.merMod(object, correlation = correlation, sigm = sig) :
  variance-covariance matrix computed from finite-difference Hessian is
not positive definite or contains NA values: falling back to var-cov estimated from RX
```

Next Attempt with optimizer L-BFGS-B:

```
summary(glmer(countOutcome ~ 1 + Exposure.f*TimePeriod1 + Exposure.f*TimePeriod2 + Exposure.f*TimePeriod3 + Exposure.f*TimePeriod4 + covariate1 + covariate2 + covariate3 + (1 | SBA),
              data=data, REML= TRUE, 
              family=Gamma(link=identity)), control=glmerControl(
                control = lmerControl(optimizer ='L-BFGS-B')))

convergence code: 0
unable to evaluate scaled gradient
Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 3 negative eigenvalues

Warning messages:
1: extra argument(s) ‘REML’ disregarded 
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  unable to evaluate scaled gradient
3: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 3 negative eigenvalues
4: In summary.merMod(glmer(sba_nyc_fe_c ~ 1 + Gcode.f * T + Gcode.f *  :
  additional arguments ignored
5: In vcov.merMod(object, use.hessian = use.hessian) :
  variance-covariance matrix computed from finite-difference Hessian is
not positive definite or contains NA values: falling back to var-cov estimated from RX
6: In vcov.merMod(object, correlation = correlation, sigm = sig) :
  variance-covariance matrix computed from finite-difference Hessian is
not positive definite or contains NA values: falling back var-cov estimated from RX
```

Next Attempt with optimizer nlminb:

```
summary(glmer(countOutcome ~ 1 + Exposure.f*TimePeriod1 + Exposure.f*TimePeriod2 + Exposure.f*TimePeriod3 + Exposure.f*TimePeriod4 + covariate1 + covariate2 + covariate3 + (1 | SBA),
              data=data, REML= TRUE, 
              family=Gamma(link=identity)), control=glmerControl(
               optimizer ='optimx', optCtrl=list(method='nlminb')))

convergence code: 0
unable to evaluate scaled gradient
Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 3 negative eigenvalues

Warning messages:
1: extra argument(s) ‘REML’ disregarded 
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  unable to evaluate scaled gradient
3: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 3 negative eigenvalues
4: In summary.merMod(glmer(sba_nyc_fe_c ~ 1 + Gcode.f * T + Gcode.f *  :
  additional arguments ignored
5: In vcov.merMod(object, use.hessian = use.hessian) :
  variance-covariance matrix computed from finite-difference Hessian is
not positive definite or contains NA values: falling back to var-cov estimated from RX
6: In vcov.merMod(object, correlation = correlation, sigm = sig) :
  variance-covariance matrix computed from finite-difference Hessian is
not positive definite or contains NA values: falling back to var-cov estimated from RX
```

Is there something I am missing? Why won't this model converge? Thank you

Comment: Normally "rescaling" means not only centering by the grand mean but also *standardizing* the variable (i.e. dividing the centered variable by the variable's standard deviation).
Following this process makes all rescaled variables comparable in terms of scale since they end all having zero mean and standard deviation equal to 1.
Note also that you should only rescale *continuous* variables, and not discrete variables taking small values or 0/1 dummy variables.

Comment: It is hard to help you out, without a reproducible example (data etc.). 
For scaling i'd suggest using `scale(variable)` which will use the population mean and standard deviation, and this should be done using the entire dataset. 
There is cases where centering alone will help. 
This seems most often to be the case when the range of the unscaled data is reasonable, but values might be very large in absolute value. 
Note you can use `help(scale)` for function documentation.
I'd suggest performing the rescaling, and if this doesn't work, check out the help page `help(convergence)`.

Comment: 2) From looking at your model, it also seems there might be some confusion between conversion from stata to `R`. In the formula i am guessing that `period` indicates a `0`/`1` dummy variable, and that you want seperate weights for each period. To keep formula notation straight you would use the `:` to multiply the two together or alternatively `I(x * y)`, the latter more (or less?) commonly known as the "as is" operator, which evaluates the inside terms before evaluating the formula. `~ x * y` would evaluate to `~ x + y + x:y` giving the time period it's own weight.